# KTable returns no data in Spring Boot application, however it can be queried

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot application working with Kafka Streams. I have a KTable with some financial currency quotes which is created like this:

```
@Bean(name = "indicativeQuotes")
public KTable<String, Quote> quoteKTable(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
    return streamsBuilder.table(quoteTopicName,
            Materialized.<String,Quote,KeyValueStore<Bytes,byte[]>>as("quoteTable")
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                    .withValueSerde(new JsonSerde<>(Quote.class)));
}
```

I @Autowire this bean in another component, and test it with the following code:

```
@Autowired
private KTable<String, Quote> indicativeQuotes;

@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    doPrint();
}

public void doPrint() {
        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Quote> store = streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams().store("quoteTable", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
        store.all().forEachRemaining(keyValue -> log.info("Key: " + keyValue.key + " Value: " + keyValue.value));
        indicativeQuotes.foreach((k,v) -> log.info(k));}
```

The code logs correct values when querying through store, but it outputs nothing in foreach(), as if like table was empty. I have also tried print() and other options - all output nothing without any exceptions.

I'm starting to think that I cant inject KTable beans like that, but Spring documentation on the topic of kafka streams is pretty scarce and I can't find good examples. Any help will be appreciated.

**Update.**

My use case is that I have a scheduled Quartz job which is supposed to write current state of KTable to a Kafka topic when triggered, like following:

```
@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    TriggerKey triggerKey = jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getKey();
    log.info("Job was triggered by: {}", triggerKey.getName());

    indicativeQuotes.filter((key, value) -> key.equals(triggerKey.getName()))
            .mapValues(quoteToCourseFixedMapper)
            .toStream()
            .peek((instrument, course)-> log.info("Sending courses for instrument: {}, {}", instrument, course))
            .to(quoteEventTopicName);
}
```

But I think this code does not work because it is not a part of processing topology and I cannot just take data from Ktable on demand. I'm a bit puzzled here, of course I can query the data through store when event is triggered, but maybe there is a better pattern for such use case? Basically I'm interested if its possible to incorporate this triggered job events as a part of processing pipeline.

Comment: I guess it's related to caching. Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html

Comment: Hi Matthias,thanks for the answer. After reading this question, answered by you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440550/kafka-stream-ktable-materialization I think that I did not quite grasp the concepts of stream processing. Can you please see the update?

Comment: Not sure if I can follow. Did you change the config to set cache size to zero but still have an issue? Also, by default, you should see output about 30 seconds, what is the default commit interval -- on commit the cache gets flushed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to publish the updates to another topic, turn the KTable to a KStream and use the to() function.

```
KTable ktable = ...;
KStream ksteram = ktable.toStream();
kstream.to("topic", Produces.with(keySerde, valueSerde))
```

The topic will contain the change log of that table.

### BUT

Apparently because of some life cycle related concepts, you can't just inject (`@autowire`) KStream/KTable. You should keep your KafkaStreams related code kind of as in-line as possible.

So in your specific case that you want the to do something with current state of table in some "random" time, you have to query the store (table). So search for kafka steams interactive queries. remember that you need to fetch data from all of your instances of the application (if you have more than 1. Or you can use a global store. Its a day or two of search.